# "present?" in haml isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a simple block of haml code using "present?" to determine if the object has an attribute:

```
    - if @available_custom_content.present?
      - @available_custom_content.each do |custom_content|
        - if custom_content.button_image.present?
```

but I get

```
 "undefined method `button_image' for #<BulletinInsert:0x007ff0206f3520>
```

... isn't the "present?" supposed to let me test whether the attribute is present?

Answer (score 2):

`present?` checks that the object is not `nil`, but it does not make any assumption about the presence of a method on the object. In this case, `@available_custom_content` is present and represents an instance of the `BulletinInsert` class, but that instance *does not* have a `button_image` method defined.

The quick solution would be to use the `try` method when calling `button_image`: `custom_content.try(:button_image)`, but that's not really a good habit to form.

Are there different types of custom content objects? It might be best to define an empty method on the `BulletinInsert` class that does nothing when `button_image` is called. Or create a `CustomContent` class that `BulletinInsert` inherits from that contains an empty `button_image` method.

Answer (score 0):

So the button_image actually referred to a mongoid relationship:

```
  has_mongoid_attached_file :button_image
```

and I guess the "present?" method couldn't handle it...

I should mention that the function DOES work with objects that have the relationship, but not with ones that do not.

Comment: The relationship would define the method on the object. In my answer above, I suggested adding an empty method: `def button_image; end`

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as kevinthompson states, is that `@available_custom_content` doesn't have a `button_image` method. `present?` checks to see whether an object is `nil` or empty:

```
nil.present?   #=> false
"".present?    #=> false
[].present?    #=> false
{}.present?    #=> false
false.present? #=> false


Object.new.present?  #=> true
"foo".present?       #=> true
[1,2,3].present?     #=> true
{foo: :bar}.present? #=> true
true.present?        #=> true
```

**In this particular instance though**, it may be that you need to `db:migrate`.  I'm making the assumption that `BulletInsert` is a model in a Rails app, by the way you refer to it as an "attribute".

If the column doesn't exist in the database, `undefined method <attribute_name>` is the error that will get thrown.  This is because Rails will define accessor methods on all columns in the database, which is what allows you to access them.  No column, no method defined.